# Why does Google AdSense see content taken from my old site on the Internet Archive as plagiarized?

Tags: google-adsense, duplicate-content, scraper-sites, internet-archive

Some years back I hosted a blog but unfortunately the blog wen off, so later I hosted another blog with a different domain because the older one has been taken.  So I grabbed all my content from http://web.archive.org/.

Recently I applied for AdSense they complained about scraped content
What should I do? Should I delete all the post and start over

Comment: If you lost the domain your blog was on originally you are probably in trouble with getting Google to locate your new site as being owned by the same person. Write new content?